# Can you have os.system keep the state of the subshell

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

My script requires me to pace back and forth on directories. I would like know if there is a way to make `os.system` keep the state, i.e. the current directory, of any previous calls, for example:
Actual result:

```
>> os.system("pwd && ls")
/Users/my_user
Music Documents Downloads
>> os.system("cd Music && pwd")
/Users/my_user/Music
>> os.system("pwd")
/Users/my_user
```

Instead I want to be able to execute the above commands and keep the current working directory on subsequent calls of `os.system`, as a terminal does:
Expected Result

```
>> os.system("pwd && ls")
/Users/my_user
Music Documents Downloads
>> os.system("cd Music && pwd")
/Users/my_user/Music
>> os.system("pwd")
/Users/my_user/Music
```

My workaround at the moment is to chain commands like this, which is tedious:
`os.system("cd downloads; echo hey; open file.txt")`, `os.system("cd downloads; echo hey; touch video.mp4")`

If there are other alternatives that don't include `os.system()`, I'm open to them.

Comment: `os.system(cd downloads; echo hey; ls)` is not valid Python syntax. Did you mean to include quotes, like `os.system("cd downloads; echo hey; ls")`? Also, I don't understand what you mean by "pace back and forth" in this context. Could you clarify that?

Comment: my bad, added them just now. I want to use it like a normal terminal, whenever you execute os.system and another one right after it, it doesn't save the last one. For example: os.system("cd downloads"), os.system("ls"). When these are executed, it'll give me the files and folders of the previous directory and NOT download's directory

Comment: [IPython](https://ipython.org) provides this out of the box. For the most part you can directly execute commands from the (python) shell eg. `ls` or `cd`. Where it doesn't understand you can just prefix with a `!` eg. `!wget example.com`. You can assign the resulting output eg. `files = !ls`. And it will of course remember environment changes like `cd`.

Comment: If you just want to change the working directory then use [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)

Answer (score 0):

Use functions from the `os` module, instead of just `os.system()`. For example

- `os.chdir()`   (equivalent of `cd`)
- `os.getwcd()`  (equivalent of `pwd`)
- `os.listdir()` (equivalent of `ls`)

And so on. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os-file-dir).

Using these commands also "keep state": your working directory will actually change for the script that uses the commands.

For specific tasks, such as selecting certain files, other modules exist. E.g. `ls *.txt` is better done in Python with the `glob` module: `glob.glob("*.txt")`. Search around for what you need.

Finally, if you want to use Python as a replacement for shell scripts, again, search around: there are some packages out there that make this easier, and include conveniences such as redirection and piping. (Then again, a shell script is quite different than Python, so if there's no, or not too much, logic in your script, use a shell script.)